# Softirq delayed because of the Heavy I/O Operation

Tags: linux, dd, usb-drive, io

I am trying to copy the contents of a 1 GB ISO file (stored in USB) to my internal storage. As part of a test when i am doing repetitive copy operation from USB to my hard drive continuously I observe a CPU stall sometimes and this makes my system miss some of the important network packets or disturbs other critical operations as well.

Steps I follow:

1. Mount the ISO (ISO-9660) on one of folders in HDD
2. Then start the copy from the Mounted folder to other folder in HDD
3. once the copy is done. Delete the copied folder.
4. Wait for 10 secs and then start the process all over again.

I have tried `copy`,`rsync`,`dd` commands. The `copy` and `rsync` weren't fruitful. But `dd` command with direct improved the performance a lot better. But unfortunately I couldn't use the direct on my mounted directory since it is readonly filesystem.

I explored few ways make my iso as a read write filesystem but it seems like  ISO-9660  file format is designed to be a Readonly filesystem.

Since direct option avoids the cache and access I/O directly. I tried to mimic that same behaviour by setting my /proc/sys/vm/dirty_backgroud_bytes and /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes  to 500000 and 550000 respectively.But it failed after few hours.

Then i tried to do copy after i disable the cache on my HDD using hdparam tool. But that also resulted in failure.

Commands used:

```
Rsync:  rsync --recursive --bwlimit=1024 <src dir>  <target dir>
Copy : cp -a <src dir> <target dir>
find the folders the in the directory and copy it one by one 
dd: dd if=<src file>  of=<target file> conv=notruc iflag=direct oflag=direct
```

How am i measuring my CPU stalls?

I capture the networks going to my target machine and i have a application (running at highest level priority at user space) which will be expecting those network packet at a particular time and raise an soft interrupt.So if the network packet has been arrived to my system and application didn't generate the interrupt then I will check the kernel trace at that moment and i can see the received network packets has not reached my application because of below queued up kernel calls

Kmem_cache_alloc

Kmem_K_alloc

rcu_utilization

kmem_kfree

kmem_cache_free

ext4_ind_map_blocks_exit

ext4_da_reserve_space

kmem_mm_page_free_direct

kmem_mm_page_alloc --> 14 times continous calls

kmem_mm_page_alloc_zone_locked --> 12 times comtinous calls

Again
kmem_mm_page_alloc -->8 times continous calls

ext3_get_blocks_enter

ext3_get_blocks_exit

ext4_da_write_begin --> frequently but not continuously
ext4_da_write_end --> frequently but not continuously
ext4_ind_map_blocks_enter --> frequently but not continuously
ext4_mark_inode_dirty --> frequently but not continuously

Can u please share your insights on this issue and the following questions?

**So What could cause a stall like this (cache)? and is there any way to avoid it**

**So is there any way to use the direct flag to copy from my mounted folder (Readonly) to the target Folder?**

**Please note my target directory where i want to copy has readwrite permissions but for some reason oflag=direct is also not working.**

***Is there any way to prepare iso with readwrite permissions?***

Comment: There's quite a few misconceptions and ambiguities that we need to clear up first. Let's start like this: Please answer **all three** of the following questions **by editing your question**: 
1. How are you copying the files using "copy,rsync,dd commands"? Please **show us the exact command lines you're executing**.
2. You say the CPU is stalled. How do you observe that? Linux waiting for data from a USB device can perfectly well do other things while it waits, especially handling network data. So your claim is *very* surprising. **How are you measuring "CPU stalls"**?

Comment: 3. The ISO file format is something different than the ISO-9660 file system. **What exactly is *in* your ISO file?**

Comment: Hi Marcus,
Yes the ISO is ISO-9660 file system. And i have edited the question as you suggested

Comment: "received network packets has not reached my application because of some queued up kernel call related to cache and memory management." please be more specific. What exactly is queued up?

Comment: Welcome, your representation of the `dd` command shouldn't be inversed? `if=<src file> of=<target file>`, and not `if=<target file> of=<src file>`? **i**nput **f**ile the source, **o**utput **f**ile the target?

Comment: @EswarReddy: I suggested an edit to the question title, to make it more clear that you are actually asking about delayed network packets, not CPU stalls (which are a different thing). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity ya you're right. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have updated the kernel events

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can try to reduce I/O latency of your network process. Depending on the use-case, your only option might be to switch to a real-time kernel like the [PREEMPT_RT patch for Linux](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start). See below for the reason why. But this is a rather extreme measure, so I'd recommend you first try some other things:

- Adjust the I/O priorities of your network process and your copy process using [ionice](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)
- Mount the file system with `mount -o sync` to disable any caching.
- When using `direct` or `sync` I/O, try varying the block size when using the `dd` command. It is conceivable that either very large or very small blocks might be a good fit, or a block size that matches your page size for example... this is just a wild guess though.

---

### Realtime Kernel

Depending on your requirements, this might be the only really viable option. Let me explain. You write:

> I capture the networks going to my target machine and i have a application (running at highest level priority at user space) which will be expecting those network packet at a particular time.

In order to diagnose the problem, we need a few things. For example: How large is the time window after which you consider a package "lost"? And how many lost packets are acceptable? It makes a huge difference whether we are talking about 500 µs or 500 ms deadline, and whether 5% or 0.05% of packets are allowed to be late or "lost".

However, regardless of the time window, this requirement will be impossible to meet in 100% of the cases unless you are running a realtime (RT) kernel. The word "realtime" means that it can make specific guarantees on how long it takes to react to a specific event, like an incoming network packet in your case.

The normal (non-realtime) Linux kernel makes *no such guarantees*, so it is even allowed to block the complete userspace for a few seconds while doing something it currently deems important, like caching, or whatever it likes. Regardless of userspace priorities. So whatever you do, without switching to an RT kernel you always have a risk of random, indefinite delay if your computer does anything else besides waiting for the network packets. And even if this were the only running process, some driver might just decide at random every few minutes/hours/days that it must take a few milliseconds to clean up some buffers *right now*.

So the answer to your implicit question *"Why does I/O make other processes react less quickly to network packets?"* is: **"Because the kernel is allowed to do that"**.

So, making the ISO filesystem read-write (which I don't think is possible) or using `direct` I/O, or any other measure apart from using an RT kernel, will not make the problem go away. It would just make it less likely to occur.

Comment: Hello Fritz,
thanks for taking time to answer my doubts. yeah you're right RT kernel can be ultimate way to ensure this behaviour.But i just wanted to explore possible ways. and i have updated a relevant title for my question as well

Comment: @EswarReddy You're welcome. I've added a couple of other suggestions that you can try first.